# operator<< chaining and function call order

Tags: c++

I have a function `centered(int a, ostream& os)`, which does a `copyfmt(os)` to output `a` to its temporary `stringstream`.

I now call it this way:

```
std::cout << std::hex << centered(a,cout) << std::dec;
```

But the output still appears decimal. OTOH, if I change it to

```
std::cout << std::hex;
std::cout << centered(a,cout) << std::dec;
```

I get the correct hexadecimal output.

It seems that `centered()` called before any `operator<<()` gets the call. Why is it so? Is  it specified in the standard, what gets called first here, or do I just get undefined behavior?

Comment: What does `centered` return?

Comment: The order of evaluation of `std::hex` and `centered(a, cout)` is *unspecified*, so you can't rely on one being evaluated before the other.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`operator<<` associates left-to-right, which means that the first statement

```
std::cout << std::hex << centered(a,cout) << std::dec;
```

is equivalent to

```
operator<<(
  operator<<(
    operator<<(
      std::cout, 
      std::hex
    ), centered(a, cout)
  ), std::dec
);
```

With this syntax, it appears that `operator<<(std::cout, std::hex)` and `centered(a, cout)` are both parameters to `operator<<`. Hence, as per the standard, their order is unspecified: It's not Undefined Behavior, but the compiler is free to choose the order it prefers.

Comment: [All of those calls but the one for `centered()` should be member function calls.](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_ostream/operator_ltlt)

Comment: @0x499602D2 how does this affect the answer?

Comment: Because then your use of the word "equivalent" will be correct.